# PROCEDURE SQL Server CON PARAMETROS A XML ERROR PLS-00049

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un paquete con un store procedure que recibe tres parametros y hace una consulta de un usuario, esa extraccion necesito pasarla a un archivo xml, pero al momento de pasarle los parametros me marca un error de "bad bind variable", si pongo un valor fijo, si me arroja el xml, alguien sabe donde tengo el error?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XX7E_EXT_FAC(P_TRX_NUM  VARCHAR2, P_CUST_NAME VARCHAR2, P_CUST_ID VARCHAR2) IS
  ctx DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
  xml CLOB;
BEGIN
  ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('SELECT CT.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID, CT.TRX_NUMBER, CT.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE, HP.PARTY_NAME

FROM RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL CT
INNER JOIN RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_all CTL_PREV ON CT.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = CTL_PREV.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
INNER JOIN HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS HCA ON HCA.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=CT.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID

INNER JOIN HZ_PARTIES HP ON HP.PARTY_ID = HCA.PARTY_ID

WHERE CT.TRX_NUMBER =  NVL('''||:P_TRX_NUM||''', CT.TRX_NUMBER) 

AND CT.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = NVL('||:P_CUST_ID||',CT.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID)');

dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(ctx, '');
xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);
dbms_output.put_line(substr(xml,1,255));
END;
```

/

Comment: Intenta no usar los ":" en tu código. No es necesario tener dos puntos si está pasando parámetros, puede asignar directamente nombres de parámetros. Espero te funcione, no lo publique como respuesta ya que no estoy del todo seguro.  Saludos.

Comment: gracias rostan, ya  me corrio, pero no me envia nada jaja, supongo que es algo en como recibe los parametros, muchas gracias

Comment: Era de que lo ponga como respuesta =/ ... haha. Saludos !